# Is it safe to commit dev and production connection strings that use windows account credentials without username and password?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, connection-string

Are the following connection strings safe to commit to version control? If not what dangers can arise. For example if I had the following connection strings with Integrated Security=True set:

In appsettings.Development.json

```
"ConnectionString": "Data Source=MYDEV\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDevCatalog;Integrated Security=True"
```

In appsettings.Production.json

```
"ConnectionString": "Data Source=MYPROD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyProdCatalog;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

Comment: There's nothing _Secret_ in there, nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

No harm done by committing it to the version control in case like this, but as a best-practice it is frowned upon.

From: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Database_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#storing-database-credentials

> Database credentials should never be stored in the application source
> code, especially if they are unencrypted. Instead, they should be
> stored in a configuration file that:
>
> Is outside of the webroot. Has appropriate permissions so that it can
> only be read by the required user(s). Is not checked into source code
> repositories. Where possible, these credentials should also be
> encrypted or otherwise protected using built-in functionality, such as
> the web.config encryption available in ASP.NET.

Comment: "frowned upon"? by whom? why? i think that's more an opinion than a fact.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I have clarified with a edit

Comment: thanks for the source. but i would argue that the provided connection strings do not have any _credentials_ in them, so this recommendation doesn't really apply. the most secret information contained is the db-server address - which should not present a significant risk as is, unless the server in question is _very_ badly secured.

Comment: Agreed with @FranzGleichmann , there are no credentials here so this does not apply. The only information here is the server address and the fact it uses Windows Authentication

Comment: How about storing connection string in a System Environment variable (Control panel -> Edit System variables -> ...) and read it from ConfigureServices() method in Startup.cs

P.S. Consider this is done inside a Production Windows Server